# Create excel file and download it

Tags: python, django

I have ***class Line*** in `models.py`. Also, I have an HTML file which consists of elements of this class. I want to add the button in HTML file which allows creating excel file and download it by the user. How I can to realize this idea.?

PS. This is maybe a stupid question, but I' beginner in Django and don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually look up `openpyxl`. [Documentation here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

And here is a chapter from `Automate the boring stuff`. [Chapter 12 : Working with Excel Files](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/)

After you've created the Excel file, you'll have to add some `headers` to the Response.

```
content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
Content-Disposition = 'attachment; filename=demo.xlsx'
```